# run nutch 1.8 or 1.9 as a hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, nutch

If I understand correctly, you can not run nutch 1.8 and 1.9 as a hadoop job, because these versions do not have a Crawl class which serves as a wrapper for all the crawl steps. This means there is no one class you can specify in the hadoop call to run a whole job. In nutch 1.7, this used to be the org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl class.

Am I missing something? Any one figure out a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong. You should use the script bin/crawl. In each step, you should see the corresponding class that you should call (in case you want to use it outside the crawl script). In addition, as far as i know the class you quoted is deprecated.

Comment: No, you just verified that my understanding is correct, and you misunderstood my question. For my need I don't want to go thru command line interface and all the bsh script. I want to in fact wrap the java Crawl class inside the ToolRunner. I dare say forcing people to use bsh by cutting away a existing java api call is not a good design choice.

Comment: So, in that case, i guess you only choice is implementing the scenario of the crawl class. Or you could use Nutch 2.x. It is not support crawling using API.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought. Just want to verify with someone.

Comment: Sorry, i meant Nutch 2.x supports starting crawling steps using API. By the way, could you accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I don't want to accept the answer when it misinterpreted my question. Maybe if you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different options for your scenario.

1- You can implement your crawl class and make ANT to build hadoop job with considering your crawl class.

2- You can schedule different classes to run on hadoop cluster in the desire order. (Inject-Generate-Fetch-Parse ...)

However I chose the first solution. But the second one works too.

Answer (score 0):

Also, take a look at https://github.com/b-cube/nutch-crawler it's a fork of Nutch 1.9 with the Crawl class so you can run it as a Hadoop job.